# In UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning the "to ViewController" has view present but "to View" is nil

Tags: ios, swift, transition

I am learning how to create custom (interactive) transitions between View Controllers. I have created setup when I want to present something modally. Presenting is working but dismissal ends up with black screen when the animation is finished.

I have noticed something strange:

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let fromV = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from)
    let toV = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to)

    let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)
    let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)
    //....
 }
```

As as I expected the `fromV` and `fromVC.view` has reference to the same view (checked in debugger, address is the same). However `toV` is `nil` while `toVC.view` has some (seems like) valid address to valid view.

How is that possible?
Shouldn't they always line up with the same values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna access the view of the `toView` controller you would use

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        if let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to) {
            let toView = toVC.view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
        //rest of code
    }
```

As per doc

> This method very efficiently captures the current rendered appearance
>   of a view and uses it to build a new snapshot view.

Hope it helps

Comment: Wow, thanks! It worked but I have idea why the snapshot fixed this nil value and the black screen at the end of animation ;)

Comment: @bdolewski :) Happy coding :)